# Is there a preference file where MobileMe username and password are saved?

Tags: snow-leopard, mobileme, preferences, login

I am looking for a preference file that contains the MobileMe username/password couple that I would need to pass to a script that starts the MobileMe synchronization. What I am trying to achieve is to start the synchronization when some conditions are verified, and disable the automatic synchronization that is started from the Mac OS X.

Is there a preference file that contains the MobileMe credentials for the currently logged in user?

Comment: My answer below does address your question as asked, but you may want to create a separate question asking how to implement what you described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Mac computers, no password information is stored in plain-text preference files -- it's all kept securely in the Keychain, which you can view using the Keychain Access utility.